# How to find MAC address on Windows 7?

Tags: networking, window, ip-address, computer-science, mac-address

i can find the MAC address of my machine with command `ipconfig /all` on command prompt. Everywhere on net says physical address is MAC address. Here is the result of command `ipconfig /all`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : XXXX
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : XXXX

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Tunnel adapter isatap.{08DA9659-BD5D-4AE2-901A-3D7C7C3ACD7C}:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B1F117B0-4FE3-4603-AF2E-DB0A97EB73A1}:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Tunnel adapter iphttpsinterface:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX

Tunnel adapter isatap.int.cpaglobal.net:

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX
```

In result i can find many entries with name Physical Address. Which one actually represent my machine mac address? My understanding is MAC address is unique for a computer whether we are connected on LAN/WLAN or not connected at all?

Answer (score 4):

A MAC address is not unique for a computer, it is unique for a Network Interface Card.
`getmac /V` gives you a more compact list of your interfaces.

EDIT:
Don't take "Card" literally as it may not be a whole separate Card connected to your motherboard. Most NICs nowadays are just integrated on-board.

[What is a MAC Address](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqhFF3bVgYg)
[Computer Networking Tutorial - 9 - Network Interface Card NIC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=778rS_FMb10)

Comment: But i am not using any Network Interface Card. Even i tried after disconnecting from net see what getmac /v result but still it gives mac address for Local Area Conn,Wireless Networ and luetooth Netwo Bluetooth. I dont know what it means?

Comment: Yes you do. Take some minutes to watch those 2 videos. I hope they can clarify things for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection` is you Wi-Fi mac and `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection` is your cable mac, every "internet device" has it's own mac adress, and here u have two depending whether you are connected using wifi or cable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use wireless connection then go to :

Network and Sharing Center >> Wireless network connection >> Details >> you will find physical address in the Details screen