# How to get MAC address from registry for WIN 7

Tags: windows-7, mac-address

I also read this [Stackoverflow incident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289173/how-to-find-mac-address-on-windows-7) but I still can not find it in registry. I would like to know, how I can retrieve the MAC address from registry on WIN 7. I have found that link [MAC address from Registry on WIN 7](http://snaked-bytes.blogspot.co.at/2011/12/how-to-change-your-mac-address-in.html) but when I check the Registry with regedit the fields for "NetworkAddress" are empty even I have one NIC installed. Has anyone here an advice? THanks

Comment: IIRC, the MAC address in the registry is the one that's been manually configured by the administrator.  Normally, it isn't there and the device uses the MAC address built into the hardware.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks a lot. Now it is clear. So I can not get the MAC by registry calls from the hardware, right?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  I could be wrong.  I know you can get it from WMI, as well as from the Win32 API, though I don't have the details available offhand.  I expect there are existing answers on SO that address this.

Comment: Here is why not to trust him. Snake argues that DeviceInstanceID contains his MAC address, and therefore he obfuscated it as such: `USB\VID_0BDA&PID_8187????` But look at the device class, "USB". That's the only reason there is a PID in there. If you're dealing with a PCI or embedded NIC, you may not even see that. While it may be possible that some unknown USB NIC manufacturer uses the MAC as part of their PID (Product ID), it's not customary. Besides, MAC addresses most certainly don't begin with 81.

Comment: More importantly, Snake is going in circles. There is nothing you will accomplish by manually adding `NetworkAddress` field to the registry that you can't do by editing the *Network Address* or *Locally Administered Address* (LAA) option (as it is correctly called in latest Windows versions) in the Properties dialog box for the NIC in Device Manager. They are one and the same. That's what that field in registry is for. And if you don't have it, it just means that LAA is not set in Device Manager (or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Windows Orb to open the Start menu.
Enter "regedit" in the search box and hit "Enter." Click on the "regedit" result under programs to launch the Windows registry browser.
Navigate, using the expandable menu in the right panel, to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Class |{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}.

Inspect the subfolders of this registry address -- numbered "0000," "0001" and so on -- to locate the device corresponding to your

Locate the "Network Address" key in the left panel followed by your computer's 12-digit MAC address.

Comment: I have done this. But the key "Network Address" is empty! I have no idea why. I have an built-in NIC.

Comment: That field in the registry is only set if the MAC Address has been modified.  It is the `Effective MAC Address` not the `Permanent MAC Address`, which is kept in hardware, not in the registry.

Comment: For the record, this text is possibly copy and pasted from this page: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/mac-address-registry-56773.html Warning: full of ads.

Comment: Jesse is onto it. As I explained in my other comments to this question, the `NetworkAddress` field is only present if an administrator overrides the the universal (UAA) address with a local (LAA) address. This is what Jesse refers to Permanent MAC Address and Effective MAC Address, which I believe to be UAA vs. LAA in VMware lingo. So if you can't find "NetworkAddress" (no space) in the `{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` class in registry, it just means that LAA is not set, Windows is using your NIC's physical MAC address, and you won't find it the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the MAC address in the registry, it is no longer in the registry as of Windows 7.  You'll need to use an alternative method to get the MAC address.

Comment: According to my research it has never been in the registry, not even in Windows XP. The web is full of misinformation. What people most often seem to refer to when they say this is the `NetworkAddress` field that can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`.

Comment: But this field is only present if an administrator overrides the the universal (UAA) address with a local (LAA) address. Which is unsurprisingly the goal for these people, but they choose the most difficult way to do so, so they can look smart. The same can be easily accomplished via Device Manager and the Properties dialog box for the NIC.